# Small Popup named EN keeps popping. After 22.10 update

Tags: keyboard, extension

I recently updated to ubuntu 22.10. Since then A small popup keeps appearing after key presses. I do not know why, or what is causing it.

It wasn't the case before the update. Tell me how to fix it.

**How do I turn it off.**

Thankyou.

[image: Image here]

Comment: The `en` indicates you are using the English language keyboard layout. If you use another language layout such as "Odia" it will be indicated there.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: chrome. It's not browser's fault. It is happening everywhere. not browser particularly

Comment: go to `Settings > Language and Region`. You have more than one language set and the option t change is reflected in the systray.

Comment: There is just one language installed : English.     English(us) and English are just variant.  [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaSMQ.png)